# Problems with layout in switch

Tags: php, css

Seems like i haven't really figured out how the switch works, cause it is impossible (for me) to get it right.

I have this code:

```
foreach ($this->timeofday as $key => $node) {
    if (get_class($node) === 'DOMElement') {
        if ($node->hasAttribute('class')) {
            switch ($node->getAttribute('class')) {
                case "cmil_salong":
                    echo '<h3>'.$node->nodeValue. '</h3>';
                    break;
                case "cmil_time":
                    echo $node->nodeValue .' ';
                    break;
                case "mv_3d":
                    echo '<span class="label label-info">3D</span> ';
                    break;
                case "cmil_rs":
                    echo '<span class="label label-info">Platser ' . $node->nodeValue . '</span> ';
                    break;
                case "mv_txt":
                    echo '<span class="label label-info">Textad</span><br>';
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (get_class($node) === 'DOMAttr') {
        if ($node->nodeName === 'href') { ?>
                <a href="<?php echo  $node->nodeValue ?>"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">book! <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window"></span></button></a><br>
            <?php
        }
    }
}
```

That produces this:

```
<h3>FS 4</h3>10:50 
<span class="label label-info">Platser 74</span> 
<span class="label label-info">3D</span> 
<span class="label label-info">Textad</span><br>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">book! <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window"></span></button>
```

[image: How it looks]

But this is the expected result:

[image: How i want it to look]

Preferably

```
<div>
    11:30 <span class="label label-info">3D</span> <span class="label label-info">textad</span> <span class="label label-info">platser 379</span>
      <span class="label label-warning"> Du kan inte l&#228;ngre k&#246;pa biljetter till den h&#228;r f&#246;rest&#228s;llningen</span>
</div>
```

Or, depending on `if ($node->nodeName === 'href')` is true:

```
<div>
    11:30 <span class="label label-info">3D</span> <span class="label label-info">textad</span> <span class="label label-info">platser 379</span>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">book! <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window"></span></button>
</div>
```

## **My question:**

1. How do i make it look like: the second image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyTTO.png

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach ($this->timeofday as $key => $node) {
    $div = "<div>";
    if (get_class($node) === 'DOMElement') {
        if ($node->hasAttribute('class')) {
            switch ($node->getAttribute('class')) {
                case "cmil_salong":
                    $div .= '<h3>'.$node->nodeValue. '</h3>';
                    break;
                case "cmil_time":
                    $div .= $node->nodeValue .' ';
                    break;
                case "mv_3d":
                    $div .= '<span class="label label-info">3D</span> ';
                    break;
                case "cmil_rs":
                    $div .= '<span class="label label-info">Platser ' . $node->nodeValue . '</span> ';
                    break;
                case "mv_txt":
                    $div .= '<span class="label label-info">Textad</span><br>';
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (get_class($node) === 'DOMAttr') {
        if ($node->nodeName === 'href') {
            $div .= '<a href="'.$node->nodeValue.'"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">book! <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window"></span></button></a><br>';
        }
    }
    echo $div .'</div>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But I still don't get the expected result